# How to check regex syntax on insert?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Problem: I have an Application (in C#) that uses a regex from a SQL Table Column to check certain things. The details of that don't really matter for the question.

The thing is: "Key" users can make entries to that table (not through the Application but directly :( ). Now it happens from time to time, that they mess up regex syntax which leads to the Application to fail and I cannot change code of the Application.

What I thought of was: maybe there is a way to have MS SQL server check Regex syntax on insert and fail the insert if incorrect.

All search results I found deal with how to use regex in TSQL for SELECT etc. But that is not what I need. I just want the regex's syntax be checked and fail the insert if it is incorrect. Also the semantics of the regex is irrelevant. I just want the program to not fail with an exception. If the regex does not do what the user expects, then that's a different story.

Has anybody done this before or has an idea how this could be done? "That's impossible" would also be an appreciated answer, so I don't have to look any further and can turn to other approaches.

Comment: This may be more work than you're willing to deal with and I don't really have the means to test this out, but it sounds like you 'might' be able to solve this with an INSTEAD OF trigger that invokes a SQLCLR function which receives the REGEX expression as a string and 'tests' it - the function could return a BIT indicating success or failure and the INSTEAD OF trigger could act accordingly to either continue with the INSERT or fail.